# How to change interface to base class?

Tags: c#, class, interface

Let's say I have two interfaces, 
`Device` and `DeviceSettings`, 
Then I have classes :

```
class DevA : Device
class DevASettings : DeviceSettings
class DevB  : Device
class DevBSettings : DeviceSettings
class DevC  : Device
class DevCSettings : DeviceSettings
```

In `Device` interface, there are two functions called:

```
DeviceSettings GetSettings();
void SetSettings( DeviceSettings setting);
```

Example :
    `DevA.GetSettings()` can get the settings from `DevASettings`

Now I want to change `DeviceSettings` from a interface to a base class.
And still want to use e.g. `DevA.GetSettings()` can get the settings from `DevASetting`

Then how do I make changes in `Device` :
e.g. how to change above two function calls so that `Device` can get the settings from its `DeviceSettings` class.

Comment: You listed `Device` functions, but make no mention of what the `DeviceSettings` interface has, yet you ask about changing the `DeviceSettings` interface into a class. I'm confused. Can you clear up your question please?

Comment: Use the naming convention for interfaces. For e.g. `IDevice` Interface instead of just `Device` it increases readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd actually make `Device` into an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Device
{
    DeviceSettings deviceSettings;

    DeviceSettings GetSettings()
    {
        return this.deviceSettings;
    }

    void SetSettings(DeviceSettings setting)
    {
        this.deviceSettings = setting;
    }
}

public class DevA : Device
{
    public DevA()
    {
        this.deviceSettings = new DevASettings();
    }

    //Do what you need with deviceSettings here
}

//Repeat for DevB/DevBSettings and DevC/DevCSettings
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make Device interface like this

```
interface Device<T> where T:DeviceSettings
{
T GetDevice();
void SerDevice(T settings);
}

class DeviceA:Device<DeviceASettings>
{
    public DeviceASettings GetDevice()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SerDevice(DeviceASettings settings)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make DeviceSettings an abstract class

Answer (score 0):

Altered the implementation with property. I don't see a problem with a base class or replacing it with its derived class. Change it according to your need.

```
interface IDevice
{
    DeviceSettingsBase DeviceSetting { get; set; }
}

class DeviceSettingsBase
{
    public virtual void DeviceSettingsName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DeviceSettingsBase");
    }
}
class DevA : IDevice
{
    public DeviceSettingsBase DeviceSetting { get; set; }
}

class DevASettings : DeviceSettingsBase
{
    public override void DeviceSettingsName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DevASettings");
    }
}

class DevBSettings : DeviceSettingsBase
{
    public override void DeviceSettingsName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DevBSettings");
    }
}

public static class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DevA devA = new DevA();
        devA.DeviceSetting = new DevASettings();
        devA.DeviceSetting.DeviceSettingsName();
        devA.DeviceSetting = new DevBSettings();
        devA.DeviceSetting.DeviceSettingsName();
        devA.DeviceSetting = new DeviceSettingsBase();
        devA.DeviceSetting.DeviceSettingsName();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
DevASettings
DevBSettings
DeviceSettingsBase
```